# Assign given text file string to variable with JavaScript completely client side

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an almost completely client side project that reads a given text file with a function and returns the contents of a file (as a string) to a variable. Some of these files may be VERY VERY large if that makes any difference on approaches. I would like a function that would perform like...

```
// fileInputID is the input type='file' id
var fileText = ReadTextFromFile('fileInputID');
```

So far I have something like this which doesn't do what I want, but it is as close as I can get so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="xFile" value="Get Data">
    <script>
      // A non-blocking sleep function (I think)
      function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      };
      async function ReadFile(fileInputID) {
        // Get the selected file from the input id.
        var file = document.getElementById(fileInputID).files[0];
        var str = "";
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function(evt) {
          str += fileReader.result;
        };
        // Read the file.
        fileReader.readAsText(file);
        // Wait for file to be completely read.
        do {
          await sleep(100);
        } while (fileReader.readyState != 2);
        console.log(str);         // Correctly prints the string.
        console.log(typeof str);  // Type of str is String.
        return str;               // OH NO! Doesn't send anything back?
      }
    </script>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <button id="output" onclick="var fileText = ReadTextFromFile('xFile'); console.log(fileText);"></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would really like to not have to send it to the server, just to have it sent back again. Also, I want it to stay a returning function instead of trying to save it to a global variable so it may stay more dynamic. Any ideas would greatly help.

Would really like to end up with something possible like...

```
var xData = ReadTextFromFile('xFile');   
var yData = ReadTextFromFile('yFile');   
plot(xData, yData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes promises are the right approach, but that polling is a bit ugly. Instead just do:

```
 function readFileFrom(fileInputID) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     var file = document.getElementById(fileInputID).files[0];
     var fileReader = new FileReader();
     fileReader.onloadend = function(evt) {
         resolve(fileReader.result);
      };
      // Read the file.
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
   });
 }
```

Now to use that just await the result:

```
 (async function() {
   const fileText = await readFileFrom("id");
 })();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Really like this approach. Though, I am now getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. I thought adding `async` to the function would help to no avail.

Comment: @bordenmike518 the `await` has to be inside an async function.

Comment: Got it working with your code and a little elbow grease! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction). This means that a call to `ReadFile()` will return a Promise, which will call back if the code inside the function returns. However, in your case it might be simpler to just pass in a callback to `ReadFile()` and not worry about Promises.

A *callback* is a function that you will call with the `str` variable inside the function once it's been computed:

```
async function ReadFile(fileInputID, callback) {    
    //... folded for clarity    
    console.log(str);       // Correctly prints the string
    console.log(typeof str);
    callback(str); // call the callback with the computed value
}

ReadFile("xFile", function (txt) { 
   do_something_with_text(txt); 
});
```

This will call `do_something_with_text` once the file has been read. At this point you can make calls to update your DOM, fire of AJAX calls, etc.

Using asynchronous calls like that has many benefits (e.g. your site doesn't hang while it's reading large files, etc.) but comes at the cost of added complexity. It's a very powerful paradigm. I hope that helps!

Comment: Wouldn't that make `continuation` a callback? The only issue I see with this is that I couldn't easily go..
`var xData = ReadFile('xFile');
var yData = ReadFile('yFile');
plot(xData, yData);`
Is this even possible?

Comment: A call to ReadFile returns a Promise, ReadFile itself is an AsyncFunction. And this works with promises if done right, falling back to callbacks migut complicate things here.

Comment: @bordenmike518 You can use currying to do what you want here: `ReadFile('xFile', (xData) => ReadFile('yFile', (yData) => plot(xData, yData))`. I think @Jonas Wilms solution is much better though. I come from a Scheme and Lisp background—Jonas's solution is much more idiomatic Javascript.

Comment: @JonasWilms Right you are! I'm not super familiar with that—your solution is much better than mine. I learned something too! ^^

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf I really like that idea and am learning to much too. I come from a heavy Python background with some C, C++, Java, ...